# How do I reach the third level?

Tags: towns

I have a fairly modest town but it appears to be somewhat stable. I have armed two people with gear from the Froggies and would like to start exploring the dungeon, but I have not been able to figure out how to get there. I tried digging and putting a ladder into a hole from the second level down, but I can not seem to be able to change my view to that level. Do I have to dig in a specific location? I do not have Solider's as of yet, are they required maybe?

Edit: Game Information - As Xenox pointed out you can find the games website [here](http://townsgame.com). It is a Java based game so in theory anywhere Java runs it should though I do believe they have specific versions for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: what game is this? what platform does it fall under? it sounds cool already.

Comment: http://www.townsgame.com/

Comment: Been meaning to try this one out.  @Xenox You can get it for slightly cheaper at [GamersGate](http://www.gamersgate.com/DD-TOWNS/towns-alpha?caff=4490881).  Also, you won't lose it.

Answer (score 3):

### Digging Down

You don't have to dig in any specific location in order to reach the next level down. You just have to dig a hole, place a ladder, and start mining under the hole.

Here's how it looks:

**1. Dig a hole and place a ladder.**

[image]

**2. Change view (see below) to next level, and mine underneath your new ladder.**

[image]

**3. Mine out further on the second level, if you'd like.**
[image]

**4. Repeat process (dig hole, place ladder...). End result should look like this:**
[image]

It is also possible to dig holes & place ladders directly under previous ladders (i.e. you can make shafts straight down). If your map has a river, be careful that you don't mine into it underground, or you will flood your mine.

When you reach the third level, you will often end up dropping your ladder down into the middle of a dungeon, in which case you won't have to do any mining - heroes in your town will just start exploring it. If you happen to drop a ladder into a block of stone instead of a dungeon chamber, then just continue mining until you break through into a chamber.

### Viewing Other Levels

To change which level you are currently viewing, you can use your mouse's **scroll-wheel** or the **level up** & **level down interface buttons** which (as of version 0.46) are located near the top left of the screen underneath the message bar:

[image: Screenshot of Towns]

Comment: You mean to keep going down I have to keep digging in the same location?

Comment: No, you don't have to place the ladders overtop of each other (although, you can if you want to make a ladder in one location that stretches across many levels, like an elevator). You can dig a hole from the top level, place a ladder down, then mine out underneath that hole. On the second level, you could dig another hole anywhere you have mined, place a ladder there, mine out underneath, etc.